# Htaccess password authentication Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When I upgraded my VPS from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 password protected directories are now giving the error below even if the correct password is entered.

```
Unauthorized: This server could not verify that you are authorized 
to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong 
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand 
how to supply the credentials required.
```

Apache error.log says "No requires line available"

Files are as follows:-

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/mysite>
Options -Indexes
AllowOverride AuthConfig
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**/var/www/mysite/.htaccess**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected"
AuthUserFile /var/www/mysite/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

**/var/www/mysite/.htpasswd**

```
admin:gIlFunhlCwBeY
```

Please will you help me to get authentication working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears apache 2.4 has added new values for the auth* modules.   A grant is required now to return similar behavior.  This is performed such as :

```
    Require all granted
```

Some of this is outlined on the Apache HTTPd documentation site:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

I suggest referencing that if you are having similar messages in your log entries.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 14.04 just edit the .htaccess file as below. It works for me:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /var/www/mysite/.htpasswd 
Require valid-user
```